# Responsive Lightbox gallery is not centered on the screen

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

I am trying to implement [flare](http://pixelentity.com/previews/components/flare/) on my website (building it).

It seems that the implementation  code is fine as the galleries loads, but the problem is that they are not centred on the screen.

I checked the css values of the images in the Lightbox and I can see that the translate3d values are wrong, but I can not figure out the cause.

```
<img class="singleImage fill" src="http://chiquititos.co.il/wp-content/uploads/house_size1.png" 
 style="-webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(262px, 276px, 0px) scale(1); ">
```

This is the link to the page (Under construction) [Website](http://chiquititos.co.il/?product=kitchen).

Any idea what could be the cause for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line in your css:

```
.singleImage {display:block !important; margin:0 auto !important;}
```

Comment: @mah2601 Thanks, now it is on the screen, but it's on the right of the screen. you can take a look again on the screen.